# Selling my cockatiel / general inquiries on an allergy

Tags: allergies, parrots, cockatiels

I had a cockatiel for about 1 month... This is the second one I got.

He is tamed partially (he still bites sometimes but not me; he doesn't really allow touching his back or wings - sometimes he will, sometimes he warns that he will bite)

He got used to the surroundings and 3/4 of the house and all the people around here. He also got used to spending time out of the cage with us and
he learned to fly to me when he wants to.

I am afraid now after reading some articles on the Internet about bird powder, because my mother says that his powder causes my sneezing and coughing.

I have been ill for about 2 weeks and I have sore throat. I visited a  doctor and took the medication for 2 weeks, but I still feel ill.

After putting him to sleep, now I feel some difficulty in breathing
and I kind of have a blocked nose. I washed it twice but it still didn't seem to fix it. So after reading those articles about allergies and hypersensitivity of bird powder I am afraid to be having these problems.

Finally if I sold it to a pet store I don't feel he would survive after bonding with us like that... A pet store or a new owner won't be the same as here.

That's 2 questions:

1. Am I sensitive to these powders?
2. If I have to sell him, would he survive that?

Also I am noticing that he sneezes a lot about 4 repetitive times rapidly then calms down (no discharge). Is there anything wrong?

At first when I got him when he took his first flights around the room his nose became seriously red from the inner... He got injured from the middle of his beak between the nose openings once from hitting the wall (at his first times i noticed he didn't know how to stop).
I added disinfectant and flour and he healed yesterday the old part pealed off and he is clean and good to go.

Comment: Can't your doctor do an actual allergy-test? It COULD be the bird, considering the timing... or pollen that start around this time of the year... or any material you use in the birds cage.

Comment: I reached a doctor who said the new female had a flu and gave me some medicine and vitamins to put in their water, and no harm to me, after the antibiotic session ended i found that the female is still ill, so I asked the pet store I got her from, he gave me another medicine for some kind of bird flu, after the medicine bottle is empty she was still ill but my male never catch the illness from her i guess, after 2 weeks she appeared to be fine, and now she is completely good active and healthy =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It doesn't seem that I am sensitive after that long time.
2. they won't survive, I tried giving them out to a friend but it didn't seem they would continue there